# Regex to extract three separate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, text

I grabbed some information from an RSS feed in XML. I need some help trying to get the values I need.

I'm hoping the regex can be fairly loose in case the tabs, newlines or spaces change, but, I'm pretty horrible at regex so I need some help.

Here's the text I have:

```
\n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY DRAW DATE: \t\t\tFriday 10/26/12 \n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY WINNING NUMBER:\t\t\t6-9-6-0\n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY PAYOUT: \t$4,000.\n\t\t\t\t\tNEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE: \tSaturday 10/27/12\n\t\t\t\t
```

Also, these `\n\t`, characters are all just plaintext.

I'd like to extract each of the values into separate variables, so:

```
MIDDAY DRAW DATE
MIDDAY WINNING NUMBER
MIDDAY PAYOUT
NEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE
```

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the results to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string.scan(/^\s*(.*?):\s*(.*?)\s*$/)
```

will give you:

```
[
  ["MIDDAY DRAW DATE", "Friday 10/26/12"],
  ["MIDDAY WINNING NUMBER", "6-9-6-0"],
  ["MIDDAY PAYOUT", "$4,000."],
  ["NEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE", "Saturday 10/27/12"]
]
```

If you just want the values without the keys, then

```
string.scan(/:\s*(.*?)\s*$/)
```

will give you:

```
[
  ["Friday 10/26/12"],
  ["6-9-6-0"],
  ["$4,000."],
  ["Saturday 10/27/12"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
^\s*MIDDAY DRAW DATE:\s*(.*?)\s*MIDDAY WINNING NUMBER:\s*(.*?)\s*MIDDAY PAYOUT:\s*(.*?)\s*NEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE:\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/qrxMyc7tT7

Each of the values you are interested in will be in a captured group.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what do u mean, is it like "MIDDAY DRAW DATE"="Friday 10/26/12"? Follow should work.

```
(\\n|\\t)*([\w\s]+(?:\s)?)(\\n|\\t)*([\w\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[*string.split(/\s{2,}/)[1..-1]]
#=> {"MIDDAY DRAW DATE:"=>"Friday 10/26/12", "MIDDAY WINNING NUMBER:"=>"6-9-6-0", "MIDDAY PAYOUT:"=>"$4,000.", "NEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE:"=>"Saturday 10/27/12"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a one-liner, it sounds like you could just split the string on `/\n\t*/` to get each name/value pair, then split each result on `: \t+` or `:\s*` to separate the names from the values and trim the whitespace. In JS, it would be something like:

```js
//JS version 1.8.1 or higher
var result = input.trim()
                .split(/\s*\n\t*/)
                .map(function(el) { return el.split(/:\s*/); });

//test:
result.reduce(function(i, j) { return i + ',\n' + j;});
```

**Edit:** If you just want the keys, it's even easier:

```
result = input.match(/[^\t]+(?=:)/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
require 'pp'

text = "\n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY DRAW DATE: \t\t\tFriday 10/26/12 \n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY WINNING NUMBER:\t\t\t6-9-6-0\n\t\t\t\t\tMIDDAY PAYOUT: \t$4,000.\n\t\t\t\t\tNEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE: \tSaturday 10/27/12\n\t\t\t\t"
pp text.strip.split("\n").map{ |l| l.split(':').map(&:strip) }
```

Resulting in:

```
[["MIDDAY DRAW DATE", "Friday 10/26/12"],
["MIDDAY WINNING NUMBER", "6-9-6-0"],
["MIDDAY PAYOUT", "$4,000."],
["NEXT MIDDAY DRAW DATE", "Saturday 10/27/12"]]
```

Basically all that needs to be done is some string clean-up, then split on new lines, then split on `':'`, with some further string clean up. No regex is needed.